# How do I capture WPF animation and export it as animated GIF?

Tags: wpf, gif

Given that I have a [WPF Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) and 10 seconds. I want to capture frames in that time period and export it as an [animated gif](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2005/05/10/3830.aspx).

How do I do that?

Functional examples please, thank you!

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454158/creating-video-from-wpf-silverlight-animation) should get you started. It explains how to get a movie file (wmv or avi) from an animation using [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx) and from that you can convert it to an animated gif using [free tools](http://www.google.se/search?q=convert+movie+file+to+animated+gif).

A quick google search revealed an online service called [Gif Ninja](http://www.gifninja.com/) that can do it (haven't tried it though so no guarantees)

Comment: I would rather render the gif binary in memory. GIF header + frame 1 + frame n ...; how to do that?